# Click Button Event in VB that displays a message about user input

Tags: vb.net, button, message

I have a really quick and simple question, I’m learning programming in C# and VB and I need to create a GUI application in Windows Form with Visual Studio. This GUI will prompt the user to enter in an integer. I believe I have this part alright but then I need to have the user click a button that will convert the user's entry to an integer and display a message indicating whether the user was successful. I think I even have the conversion done correctly but I am having a problem displaying that message if the user was successful. Basically I need to know how to function the click method in VB that will allow this message to appear. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. The following code is what I have already written for this project:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub EvaluateInput()
        Dim InputValue As String
        InputValue = ValueTextBox.Text
        If IsNumeric(InputValue) Then
            MessageBox.Show(InputValue & " is a number.")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show(InputValue & " is not a number.")
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click 'Continue Button

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click 'Exit Button
        Dim button As DialogResult
        button = MessageBox.Show _
        ("Are you sure you want to exit this application?", _
        "Message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)

        If button = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
            Me.Close()
        Else
            'Do Nothing    
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, then you would need a simply change:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) _
        Handles Button2.Click 'Continue Button
  EvaluateInput()
End Sub
```

When you press Button2, it will call the EvaluateInput sub and display a message accordingly.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. I knew it was that simple but I had a brain fart...lol Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the little edit too. I can never get these posts to line up correctly when I post the actual code.